# Issue connecting Node server to MySQL when both images are running on docker-compose

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, node.js-typeorm

I have this `docker-compose.yml` file:

version: "3"

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bl
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql

  server:
    env_file: "./server/.env"
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: "server"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /server

COPY . .
COPY package*.json ./
COPY .env ./ 

RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 3306

ENV NODE_ENV=docker

RUN yarn typeorm:migrate
RUN yarn typeorm:run-migrations

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

When trying to build both of them, I am getting an error on this line:  `RUN yarn typeorm:migrate`.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
 > [7/8] RUN yarn typeorm:migrate:                                                                                             
#10 0.857 yarn run v1.22.19                                                                                                    
#10 0.943 $ yarn create:migrate-repo && yarn run typeorm -- -d ./src/systems/typeOrm.config.ts migration:generate ./src/migrations/migration
#10 1.344 $ mkdir -p ./src/migrations
#10 1.757 warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
#10 1.769 $ ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d ./src/systems/typeOrm.config.ts migration:generate ./src/migrations/migration
#10 7.524 Error during migration generation:
#10 7.527 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
#10 7.527     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
#10 7.527   errno: -111,
#10 7.527   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
#10 7.527   syscall: 'connect',
#10 7.527   address: '127.0.0.1',
#10 7.527   port: 3306,
#10 7.527   fatal: true
#10 7.527 }
#10 7.565 error Command failed with exit code 1.
#10 7.565 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
#10 7.594 error Command failed with exit code 1.
#10 7.594 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
------
```

The error is occurring because the server cannot establish a connection with the `db` image.

This is my `DataSource`:

```
export const appDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "mysql",
  host,
  port,
  username: rootUser,
  password,
  database,
  entities: [Company, Order],
  migrationsTableName: "migrations",
  migrations: [`${__dirname}/../migrations/*.ts`],
});
```

Here is a list of things that I was tring to do. in order to solve the issue:

1. Create a network bridge between the two images. It did not work.

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bl
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - my-network

  server:
    env_file: "./server/.env"
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: "server"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

2. Change the name of the `host` to the name of my `db` image with and without my network bridge.
3. I was trying even to get the direct IP of the `db` image and it did not work.

```
docker inspect db | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.23.0.2",
```

Comment: Share your connection string, i.e. the env file parameters that you are using in the `server` service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `db` address is not available in the build time.

```
RUN yarn typeorm:migrate 
RUN yarn typeorm:run-migrations
```

Remove these line from the Dockerfile and add to a command directive in the `server` service:

```yaml
  server:
    env_file: "./server/.env"
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: "server"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - my-network
    command:
      - yarn typeorm:migrate && yarn typeorm:run-migrations && yarn start
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the way I've fixed it was:

I've added a `command` line in my `docker-compose.yml` file as Andromeda suggested.

My `docker-compose` file looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bl
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql

  server:
    env_file: "./server/.env"
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: "server"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: sh -c "yarn typeorm:migrate && yarn typeorm:run-migrations && yarn start"
```

And my `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /server

COPY . .
COPY package*.json ./
COPY .env ./ 

RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 3306

ENV NODE_ENV=docker

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

The `scripts` that I am running from `package.json` are:

```
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli",
    "create:migrate-repo": "mkdir -p ./src/migrations",
    "typeorm:migrate": "yarn create:migrate-repo && yarn run typeorm -- -d ./src/systems/typeOrm.config.ts migration:generate ./src/migrations/migration",
    "typeorm:run-migrations": "yarn typeorm migration:run -- -d ./src/systems/typeOrm.config.ts",
```

In order to use the `db` image in my service, I needed to use "db" as a `host`:

```
export const appDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "mysql",
  host: "db", // <--- use "db" instead of "localhost".
  port,
  username: rootUser,
  password,
  database,
  entities: [Company, Order],
  migrationsTableName: "migrations",
  migrations: [`${__dirname}/../migrations/*.ts`],
});
```